# Get connected port number and hub number of the device

Tags: windows, powershell

I used to get Device information of the connected USB device using the following command

```
gwmi Win32_USBControllerDevice |%{[wmi]($_.Dependent)} |
 Sort Manufacturer,Description,DeviceID |
 Ft -GroupBy Manufacturer DeviceID
```

How to get connected port number and hub number of the device using Windows Powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to list the USB device IDs using WMI, then lookup each in the registry to get the location information, if any exists...

```
  $devices = gwmi Win32_USBControllerDevice |%{[wmi]($_.Dependent)}|select DeviceID
$devices.DeviceID | %{Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\$_"}|
 select Mfg,DeviceDesc,HardwareID,LocationInformation,Class
```

Produces info like this on my machine:

```
Mfg                 : @msmouse.inf,%msmfg%;Microsoft
DeviceDesc          : @msmouse.inf,%hid.mousedevice%;HID-compliant mouse
HardwareID          : {HID\VID_15CA&PID_00C3&REV_0512, HID\VID_15CA&PID_00C3, 
                      HID_DEVICE_SYSTEM_MOUSE, HID_DEVICE_UP:0001_U:0002...}
LocationInformation : 
Class               : Mouse


Mfg                 : @usb.inf,%generic.mfg%;(Standard USB Host Controller)
DeviceDesc          : @usb.inf,%usb\composite.devicedesc%;USB Composite Device
HardwareID          : {USB\VID_0408&PID_2FB1&REV_0901, USB\VID_0408&PID_2FB1}
LocationInformation : Port_#0004.Hub_#0003
Class               : USB
```